# Iterate over middle third of map

Tags: scala, dictionary, loops

I have a scala `Map[String, String]` and I am comparing a part of the key to its value only for the mid-third of the map. Since it is not easy to iterate using indices in a map, I came up with the following but it does not work.

```
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    val mapSize = sortedMap.size/3
    for((key,value) <- sortedMap) {
        j+=1
        if((i < 3) && (key.split(' ').take(1).mkString==value)&&(j>mapSize)){
            Accuracy += 1
            i += 1
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the method `slice(from: Int, until: Int)` and then only iterate over the middle third of the sorted map. Something like

```
val mapSize = sortedMap.size
for ((key, value) <- sortedMap.slice(mapSize/3, 2*mapSize/3)) {
  ...
}
```

Note that this is only reliable if the underlying map is sorted (as seems to be the case in your example). You also might have to adapt the index calculation a little bit, depending on what exactly you consider the middle third for maps whose size is not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the map to a stream, modify the stream to remove the first third and the last third and then iterate through the remaining middle third.

```
val middle = sortedMap.toStream.drop(sortedMap.size / 3).dropRight(sortedMap.size / 3)
middle.foreach(println _) // replace println with your key test
```

For the key test, you could use a pattern match on

```
case key if key.split(' ')(0) == value => ...do something...
```